# For-loop over multiple files in same directory in Python

Tags: python, for-loop

So I already tried to check other questions here about (almost) the same topic, however I did not find something that solves my problem.

Basically, I have a piece of code in Python that tries to open the file as a data frame and execute some eye tracking functions (PyGaze). I have 1000 files that I need to analyse and wanted to create a for-loop to execute my code on all the files automatically.

The code is the following:

```
os.chdir("/Users/Documents//Analyse/Eye movements/Python - Eye Analyse")

directory = '/Users/Documents/Analyse/Eye movements/R - Filtering Data/Filtered_data/Filtered_data_test'

for files in glob.glob(os.path.join(directory,"*.csv")):
    #Downloas csv, plot 
    df = pd.read_csv(files, parse_dates = True)
    #Plot raw data
    plt.plot(df['eye_x'],df['eye_y'], 'ro', c="red")
    plt.ylim([0,1080])
    plt.xlim([0,1920])
    #Fixation analysis 
    from detectors import fixation_detection 
    fixations_data = fixation_detection(df['eye_x'],df['eye_y'], df['time'],maxdist=25, mindur=100)
    Efix_data = fixations_data[1]
    numb_fixations = len(Efix_data) #number of fixations
    fixation_start = [i[0] for i in Efix_data] 
    fixation_stop = [i[1] for i in Efix_data] 
    fixation = {'start' : fixation_start, 'stop': fixation_stop}   
    fixation_frame = pd.DataFrame(data=fixation)
    fixation_frame['difference'] = fixation_frame['stop'] - fixation_frame['start']
    mean_fixation_time = fixation_frame['difference'].mean() #mean fixation time 
    final = {'number_fixations' : [numb_fixations], 'mean_fixation_time': [mean_fixation_time]} 
    final_frame = pd.DataFrame(data=final)
    #write everything in one document
    final_frame.to_csv("/Users/Documents/Analyse/Eye movements/final_data.csv")
```

The code is running (no errors), however : it only runs for the first file. The code is not ran for the other files present in the folder/directory.
I do not see where my mistake is?

Comment: it seems that you're dumping the data to the same file at each iteration. Wouldn't that be the issue?

Comment: Please post a MCVE and explain what makes you say that "it only runs for the first file"

Comment: I see that it only runs for the first file, because at the end it writes only one line of the  final_frame in the csv. However, I'm now testing it with 2 files and should get 2 lines in the final_data.csv. In addition, in the first line I ask it to draw a graph and it only produces one graph (and not two)

Comment: @Sarah.d That's consistent with just *one* file being processed, not necessarily the *first* file. I suspect you are seeing the results of the *last* file being processed.

Comment: What is your output if you add `print(files)` as the first line of the loop?

Comment: @chepner: if I add print(files) as the first line, I get exactly the same as before.

Comment: @Sarah.d I believe Jean-Francois is correct, please try the edit I suggested in the answer below.

Comment: The respons of @Vidak solved my problem! I now get two lines in my csv file instead of only one! Thanks!

Comment: @Sarah.d The purpose was to verify which file(s) your loop was actually iterating over, not to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your output file name is constant, so it gets overwritten with each iteration of the for loop. Try the following instead of your final line, which opens the file in "append" mode instead:

```
#write everything in one document
with open("/Users/Documents/Analyse/Eye movements/final_data.csv", "a") as f:
    final_frame.to_csv(f, header=False)
```